# How to retrieve data from DataTable by iterating through the rows

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I want to put this into a loop, the code is working fine 
but I can't make a loop for it.
When it detects a new data on a table it will automatically add 
another item, on my code below it only shows two user controls but I need to generate all of the value in the table.
Here is the code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=rmsdb;username=root;password=");
    MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlDataAdapter da;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LRNincrement();

    }
    int poss = 10;
    public void AddItems(string Text, bool Checked)
    {
        DynaItems item = new DynamicUserControl.DynaItems(Text, Checked);
        PanelContainer.Controls.Add(item);
        item.Top = poss;
        poss = (item.Top + item.Height + 10);
    }

    private void additembtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LRNincrement();
        txt.Text = "";
    }
    private void LRNincrement()
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT lrnnumber from rmsdb.studentstable";
        command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(table);
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string trylol = table.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            AddItems(trylol, true);
        }
        if (table.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            string trylol1 = table.Rows[1][0].ToString();
            AddItems(trylol1, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You *don't* need to add items one by one. You can bind the control to any data source. DataTables were the first, after 2.0 (I think) you could bind to any collection. All built-in controls support data binding

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below the code

```
        {
            string trylol = table.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            AddItems(trylol, true);
        }
        if (table.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            string trylol1 = table.Rows[1][0].ToString();
            AddItems(trylol1, true);
        }
```

with

```
    string itemName = string.Empty;

    for(int i = 0; i< table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       itemName = table.Rows[i][0].ToString();
       AddItems(itemName, true);
    }
```

I am not able to test this code. But hope this help you to find the solution.

Comment: i solved it thankyou i used to write my own code here it is : 
   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
              {
                  AddItems(row["LrnNumber"].ToString(), true);
              }
        }